# Customize jQuery serialize output

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization

I have inputs that have names like `Education.School`, `Education.Degree`. I want `jQuery.serialize()` to generate fields without prefix `Education`. Is there a proper way to do this or I just change those `name` attributes manually with JavaScript before serializing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`$.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) for this

```
var formFields = {};

$.each($("form").serializeArray(), function(_, field) {
    formFields[field.name.split(".")[1]] = field.value;
});

console.log(formFields, $.param(formFields));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4yj3/)